# Disable QAction if the QTreeView item has no children

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview

I have `QTreeView` populated from database.

I have contextmenu configured as:

```
ui->treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

I have the method to look for a right click to open contextMenu on the item.

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
QModelIndex idx = ui->treeView->indexAt(pos);
if (!idx.isValid())
        {return;}
else{
   QPoint globalPos = ui->treeView->mapToGlobal(pos);
   QAction* selectedItem = contextMenu->exec(globalPos);
    if (selectedItem){
        qDebug () << selectedItem;
    }
}
```

h.file

```
QMenu *contextMenu;
```

How do I check if the selected item from `QTreeView` is not a parent of any item & it has a parent.

Should I include `QTreeView` and `QStandardItem` code here to see or that's irrelevant?

Comment: With a `QModelIndex`, you can ask the [`model()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model) of `QTreeView` what you want to know. E.g. to _check if the selected item from QTreeView is not a parent of any item & it has a parent_: `!ui->treeView->model()->hasChildren(idx) && ui->treeView->model()->parent(idx).isValid()`. `model()` returns a pointer to the [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) which is used for tree view.

Comment: I didn't get exactly for which items you want a context model? For _selected item from QTreeView is not a parent of any item & it has a parent_? In this case, I'm afraid the condition in my sample code still needs some minor fixing.

Comment: Your example is correct. I have 2 different contextMenus, one for the parent items(like the branch) and one for the items which are the leaf items.

Comment: When I wrote the comment I changed the sample code slightly (before or after - I forgot). However, you may fiddle with `!`, `&&`, `||` until it matches your intentions.

Comment: Just saw your title: _Disable QAction if the QTreeView item has no children_ I'm afraid the first version was better than the second - I will change it again...

Answer (score 1):

The Qt doc. has a dedicated chapter for this topic:

### [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)

which I recommend to get an overview.

Concerning the actual question of OP:

> How do I check if the selected item from QTreeView is not a parent of any item & it has a parent.

The `QTreeView` inherits [`QAbstractItemView::model()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model) which provides a pointer to the [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) which in turn provides the underlying model data for the rendered tree view items.

Any provided `QModelIndex` in a view should refer to this model.

The [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) provides a variety of methods to retrieve data concerning visualization and relations of model items. The `QTreeView` uses this but it should be used as well for any added function.

So, *selected item is not parent of any item* is turned around into "selected item has no children" for which [`QAbstractItemModel::hasChildren()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#hasChildren) is good for:

> #### bool QAbstractItemModel::hasChildren(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const
>
> Returns true if parent has any children; otherwise returns false.
>
> Use rowCount() on the parent to find out the number of children.
>
> Note that it is undefined behavior to report that a particular index hasChildren with this method if the same index has the flag Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren set.
>
> **Note:** This function can be invoked via the meta-object system and from QML. See Q_INVOKABLE.
>
> **See also** parent() and index().

and *it has a parent* can be retrieved using [`QAbstractItemModel::parent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#parent):

> #### QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
>
> Returns the parent of the model item with the given index. If the item has no parent, an invalid QModelIndex is returned.
>
> A common convention used in models that expose tree data structures is that only items in the first column have children. For that case, when reimplementing this function in a subclass the column of the returned QModelIndex would be 0.
>
> When reimplementing this function in a subclass, be careful to avoid calling QModelIndex member functions, such as QModelIndex::parent(), since indexes belonging to your model will simply call your implementation, leading to infinite recursion.
>
> **Note:** This function can be invoked via the meta-object system and from QML. See Q_INVOKABLE.
>
> **See also** createIndex().

Putting this together, OPs function should look like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QModelIndex idx = ui->treeView->indexAt(pos);
    if (!idx.isValid()
      || !ui->treeView->model()->hasChildren(idx)
      && !ui->treeView->model()->parent(idx).isValid()) {
      return;
      // bail out -> no context menu for leaf nodes or toplevel nodes
    } else {
       QPoint globalPos = ui->treeView->mapToGlobal(pos);
       QAction* selectedItem = contextMenu->exec(globalPos);
        if (selectedItem) {
            qDebug () << selectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure whether this matches exactly OPs required behavior. It might be necessary to fix the condition but this should be not that hard.